# Can I get tmux split screen to retain the pwd?

Tags: tmux

Say my present working directory is /home/abc/documents/xyz. Now in tmux, when I split my screen, the new pane defaults to the /home/abc directory. I want the pwd to be retained upon splitting.

Comment: Similair question on [unix.exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12032/create-new-window-with-current-directory-in-tmux), describes how to open new window while retaining the current pwd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put something like the following in your `tmux.conf` file:

```
bind <key of your choice> default-path $(pwd) \; split-window\; set default-path ~/
```

This binds to the chosen  or  a command which changes the default path for new panes to the current directory of the current pane (via the output of `pwd`) and then splits the pane, and then binds it back to home.

I read this trick on [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Split_window_and_retain_current_directory) a while back. There's another more in-depth method that uses `cd` if you follow the link, though it has its own issues so I'd personally recommend sticking with what's shown above.

Comment: The tip you linked to works when it is executed from a shell command line because the shell expands the `$()` command substitution. However, this same command cannot actually “be easily bound to a key” because *tmux* does not do command substitution for the value given to `set default-path` (even if it did, the effective cwd would be that of the server, not that of the foreground process of the active pane).

Comment: Also, there really is no need to even mess with `default-path` for the case of creating a pane/window with the same cwd as an existing shell because `tmux split-window`/`tmux new-window` from (e.g.) a shell will pass its cwd (inherited from its parent, (e.g.) the shell) to the process started for the new pane.

Comment: A note since I'm not allowed to make that small of an edit: the first `default-path` above should be `set default-path`.

Answer (score 6):

The `default-path described` on a previous answer is no longer a compatible, this behavior was changed from tmux 1.8 to tmux 1.9.

The way to do this now is to have binds that do `neww -c '#{pane_current_path}'` or the same with `split-window`.

Please refer to the changes exposed here: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/CHANGES , in the section that reads `CHANGES FROM 1.8 to 1.9, 20 February 2014`.

Answer (score 1):

theres a zsh-plugin for that https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/last-working-dir/last-working-dir.plugin.zsh

coincidentally I have this behaviour via a ssh:ed session but I don't know what setting this is.

Comment: This solution has a bit of a lag to it, but works and is the easiest method given you use `oh-my-zsh`.